# Multiple custom field in a custom group

Tags: custom-fields

I need to create a new tab for a Contact, with a custom field with multiple values. So I think I have to create a Custom group displayed in a tab, but then I can not add another custom group in this custom group, or a multi-valued custom field.....

How can I do that ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to edit your custom group and enable multiple records. Users then will be able to add the field more than once.

[image]

Depending on your use case, the "Tab with table" may look better than the "Tab" display. Tab with table is easier to view and edit in most cases; try them and see which you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not exactly what I want. For example : a contact has "children" group (multiple records because a contact can have many children). Custom group "children" contains fields ("firstname", "date of birth") and I need to add another field  "schools" for example. This field should be a group with multiple records, because a child can have many schools (and a school could have many fields)....

Comment: Mostly I think people would be using Relationships for this type of situation. Maybe you can expand your question, explain what you are trying to do, and confirm why Relationships isn't going to work for your use case.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain : many people will work on Contacts. One person of one department will need some informations, another one from another department will need other informations and so on. So on each Contact I add a Tab for each department (it is more clear than everything in the summary screen). But in one department, I need a group fields for a "folder" : for example il will contain "date", "note", "finished" fields. So it is not a relationship because my "folder" is not a contact, and departments are not contacts too. Is it more clear ?